# Update file with data from keyboard using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Sed is drawing me nuts !! 
I'm trying to append a file with a input data from keyboard. This data needs to be put in the line after some text matches criteria.

My file:

```
location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) {
allow 10.10.1.25;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
location ~* \.php$ { try_files /dummy @proxy; }
deny all;
}
```

That is the part of my script where I'm collecting data from keyboard and run sed:

```
echo "Type IP you want to whitelist > "
read ip
sed -i '/allow 10.10.1.25;/i allow ${ip};'  test.txt
```

My file now looks like:

```
location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) {
allow $ip
allow 10.10.1.25;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
location ~* \.php$ { try_files /dummy @proxy; }
deny all;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ? I want to value from this variable was in the file not $ip. How my sed command should looks like if I wanted this to be inserted after this line:

```
location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) {
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You have `${ip}` inside the single quotes, so bash is not doing the variable substitution.

Comment: And if you want it to go AFTER, you need `a` (append), not `i` (insert).

Comment: That made a trick, however I can't get this line: location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) { working when sed. Right now as you can see I'm seding for allow 10.10.1.25; and I need to seding for that line above

Comment: `sed "/^location ~\* ^\/(index\\\.php\/admin|admin) {/a allow ${ip}" test.txt`